# "Statement seems to have no effect" error received when trying to repeat a loop by changing the number of times the loop should repeat from 0 to 3

Tags: python-3.x, loops

So I was just trying to understand the `while` loop in python 3 by creating a simple password-unlock system that will make you wait 30 seconds after 3 incorrect attempts. Well the code works, but now, I want it to loop after the 30 second delay and prompt the user for input again.
Here's the code:

```
'''
Purpose of code: To make a password protector that will lock for 30 seconds after 3 
failed attempts.
Plan:
Use input to take user input(possible password.
If input was correct, give you access
If input was wrong, give 2 more chances.
After 3 incorrect attempts, lock "system" for 30 seconds (or just waiting as a 
timer).
'''
import time

f_a = 3

while f_a > 0:
set_password = "passw0rd"
user_input = input("Please enter your password :\n")

if set_password == user_input:
    print("You got access !")
    break
else:
    f_a = f_a - 1
    print("Error, you have", f_a, "attempts left.")
    if f_a == 0:
        print("Time out for 15 seconds.")
        print("15")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("14")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("13")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("12")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("11")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("10")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("09")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("08")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("07")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("06")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("05")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("04")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("03")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("02")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("01")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("00")
        time.sleep(1)`
```

So now I wanted the code to repeat itself after "time.sleep(1)" .One way i tried was by f_a == 3 after the last line. But i got a warning "Statement seems to have no use.". I then tried "while f_a == 0:
f_a == 3 ".
Failed as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code indentation is off: the while loop body should be indented, otherwise you will just get a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how a `while` loop works. You don't have to check the condition separately in the loop body, that is implied in the expression between `while` and the colon `:`. As long as you make sure that this expression will change its value, e.g. by decreasing a counter, you're fine.

Adding a stand-alone `f_a == 3` in the loop body will be evaluated to either True or False. But then, nothing will happen with that value if you don't assign it to a variable or check it in a `if` or `while` statement. That's why you get the warning `Statement seems to have no use.`. It's equivalent of just having `True` or `False` on a separate line with nothing else.

Comment: Hmmmm... so the `==` operator is just for `True` and `False`, and using the `=` operator would have been correct ?

Comment: I just checked the script with `f_a = 3` at the end of the code and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Command_Blocks the `==` operator does a comparison and returns a boolean value (i.e. `True` or `False`). The `=` is for assignment, i.e. you're changing the value of `f_a`. But you already do that at the beginning of the loop: `f_a = f_a - 1` so there's no need to do that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, even tho i wrote `f`_a = f_a -1` at the beginning of the loop, I wanted the loop to repeat itself after the 15 second countdown . The best way to do this, was by adding `f_a = 3` at the end of the code, because then it will automatically make the loop repeat itself as `while f_a > 0:` is checking the value of f_a and will run if `f_a = 0` . Also, as I mentioned, the `f_a` will become 0 after 3 incorrect attempts, which ultimately results in th countdown.

Comment: @Command_Blocks this reasoning is a bit convoluted. Generally, it is a Very Bad Idea to modify the loop variable (in your case, `f_a`) as it leads to harder to understand code and therefore subtle bugs. I recommend you to try to avoid that.

Comment: ok, will see how I can avoid that

Answer (score 0):

```
''' try this'''
import time

f_a = 3
flag=1
while flag==1:
    while f_a > 0:
        set_password = "passw0rd"
        user_input = input("Please enter your password :\n")

        if set_password == user_input:
            print("You got access !")
            flag=0
            break
        else:
            f_a = f_a - 1
            print("Error, you have", f_a, "attempts left.")
            if f_a == 0:
                print("Time out for 15 seconds.")
                print("15")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("14")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("13")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("12")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("11")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("10")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("09")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("08")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("07")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("06")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("05")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("04")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("03")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("02")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("01")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("00")
                time.sleep(1)
    if flag==0:
        break
    else:
        f_a=3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if I am correct, what you have done is creating a `while` loop and putting the main loop inside of that, and then when the user puts a correct password, it breaks the `flag==1` loop and continues with the rest of the code, right?